# 500 Error when calling Google Books API from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-books-api

I'm calling Google Books API in a project using Firebase with code similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570263/httpserror-when-calling-google-books-api-from-firebase-cloud-function).

However, I'm running into an issue with production.  When I try this locally I can connect to the `Google Books API` no problem, but it keeps failing on production with a `500 error` and the only details I get are:

```
{"error":{"message":"INTERNAL","status":"INTERNAL"}}
```

Any ideas what I should try here?  I've set my API key to be unrestricted in the developer's console and am stuck.

Here is my cloud call from firebase:

```
export const getGoogleBooks = functions.https.onCall(
    async function(data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) {
       const query: string = data.query;
       console.log(`Received query loud and clear: ${query}`);
       try {
          const res = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}&key=xxxx`);
          const json = await res.json();
          return json;
       } catch(err) {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", 'Failed to search books online');
       }
    }
);
```

Here is what my API key permissions look like in Google Console:
[image: Google API Console]

My requests seem fine when I try them locally, in Postman, or a Browser, but on production I'm getting the error message mentioned above.

Comment: pls, provide your code, a similar code is not the same

Comment: Just updated with my cloud call from Firebase and a picture of my Google API console settings in case there is something wrong there.

Comment: did you identify where it throws the error?

Comment: const res = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}&key=xxxx`);

Comment: Well this isn't a complete answer but I got it working by moving my fetch call into the client (instead of a cloud function in firebase).  Just commenting here in case it's helpful to anyone else